# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: php

Can anyone please help me, this function was working correct on my localhost but when i did site live i am facing this issue.

```
 private function _get_token( $userData = array() ) {
        $token = sha1(uniqid());

        $oldData = get_option(self::PREFIX .'data') ?: array(); //Error on this line
        $data = array();
        $data[$token] = $userData;
        update_option(self::PREFIX .'data', array_merge($oldData, $data));

        return $token;
    }
```

Comment: `?:` why both with each other??

Comment: ternary operator syntax is :
`$var = (5 > 2 ? true : false); // returns true`

Comment: What's the PHP version on the server? According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), leaving out the middle part of the ternary operator wasn't allowed before PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is about `?:`, This is the ternary operator, so you need to set the value of the condition when ture and also for false, In your case you just set the value for false.

This is your

```
$oldData = get_option(self::PREFIX .'data') ?: array();
```

Should Be:

```
$oldData = get_option(self::PREFIX .'data') ? get_option(self::PREFIX .'data') : array();
```

I think so, Let me know if this is the issue or not.

Comment: Awesome Frayene for descriptive answer and it works

Comment: It solves the error, but I think it may be better to use `get_option()` just once, (depending on what `get_option()` function does). So checking the value to assign to `$oldData` var before to ternary operator assignament could be more efficent solution.

Comment: But i am confuse why this error not come on localhost

Comment: Because on localhost you have latest php version which allow for ?:

Comment: @NachoM., Yes you are right.

Comment: @JunaidKhan, If this is solved your problem than mark this as answer so people know about this.

Comment: @nospor, are you sure the latest PHP allow `?:`

Comment: I marked it as answer and nospor you are right i have latest version of php on localhost and my hosting company has old version
Thankyou all for quick help

Comment: @FrayneKonok  yes, I am sure. You can check here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php  *Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise*

Comment: okey thanks for the information.